# Model query, filtering with choices

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model field as below.

```
GENDER_IN_CHOISES = (
        (MALE, _('Male')),
        (FEMALE, _('Female')),
        (UNDEFINED, _('Undefined')),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_IN_CHOISES, default=UNDEFINED)
```

I am making queries with object filtering however below does not satisfy my needs.

```
Users.objects.filter(gender__contains='male')
```

Do you know a way to make queries to choice fields?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? errors? invalid results? what do you expect to happen that isnt currently?

Comment: I mean it is not working for me.

Comment: "not working" is a very vague and broad statement.

Answer (score 3):

if `MALE` and `FEMALE` are defined as `'ML'` and `'FL'`, then the `contains='male'` or the case-insensitive version `icontains='male'` queries would be useless because the database fields contain 'ML' and 'FL'

Your query would be more along the lines of:

```
Users.objects.filter(gender__in=('ML', 'FL'))
```

But you should reuse your constants to keep the code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

```
Users.objects.filter(gender__in=(MALE, FEMALE))
```

Or, exclude the undefined genders

```
Users.objects.exclude(gender=UNDEFINED)
```

Comment: it is working like this `Users.objects.filter(gender__in=('ML', 'FL'))`. But this does not satisfy me...

Comment: I have a charfield as above and trying to make a filter (ie. firstname contains 'umut'...) I am posting the text from frontend to backend via rest API. `[{"field":"first_name","condition":"icontains","text":"umut"}] ` becomes `exec 'users = users.objects.filter('+field+'__'+condition_+'="'+text+'")' `. Result of this filtering I get the final users. I have no idea how to do this method on fields with choices. For example, `[{"field":"gender","condition":"icontains","text":"ale"}] `

Comment: The feeding of strings from client to server to concatenate and the `exec` not just lacks elegance and order, but is very much a bad practice for security. REST APIs have filter support, [example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#django-rest-framework-filters-package). If you tell me which REST framework you're using and ask a separate question I might be able to help or at least help write a REST view that does the filtering. As for this question, we've already answered it since the query works.

Comment: I am using django-rest-framework. I know it is not elegant but I am considering security measures for my API.